# « Braided in cornrows » (coiffure): traduction et variante(s) ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, terminologie, coiffure

Voici une phrase en anglais prescrivant les paramètres d'une coiffure composée d'une forme de [*tresse*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tresse):

> Hair may be braided in symmetrical fore and aft rows, **cornrows**, which
>   must be close to the head, leaving no hair unbraided.<sup>1</sup>
>
> [...] (je souligne)

Des cheveux *tressés en rangs/rangées/champ de maïs*, c'est plutôt amusant, mais je ne trouve rien à cet effet. On voit une entrée de 2014 au *GDT (Québec)* basée sur [natte/natter](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/natte): il s'agit des [*nattes collées*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26529252); au cuir chevelu faut-il comprendre. Le [*Littré*](http://www.littre.org/definition/natte) indique qu'une *natte* n'a pas nécessairement trois brins. Par ailleurs, l'outil *ngram* (Google) illustre que les [*« tresses plates »*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tresses%20plates&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctresses%20plates%3B%2Cc0) (et il ne s'agit pas uniquement que de cheveux ici) fut beaucoup moins utilisé au 20<sup>e</sup> siècle qu'au siècle le précédant.

Quel est le terme généralement utilisé en France et ailleurs dans la francophonie pour désigner et la coupe et les tresses/nattes en *cornrows* ? Est-ce uniforme, récent et sur quoi ça s'appuie ? Comment rend-on (le mieux) cette idée de *braided in cornrows*?

---

<sub>1. Il s'agissait d'une information sur le changement des règles visant les cheveux des femmes au sein de la marine (Navy) Américaine; et donc le [site](http://www.navy.mil/ah_online/um/FHCR.html) mis au point pour illustrer les nouvelles règles (Female Hair Regulations). Si un peu surréaliste, certainement intéressant !</sub>

Comment: Bravo pour les recherches préalables. Si seulement toutes les questions étaient aussi bien posées !

Comment: @RomainVALERI Merci! Avec plaisir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En cherchant sur un site de coiffure afro, j'ai trouvé *tresses plaquées*.

Google donne des résultats similaires pour [braided cornrows](https://www.google.fr/search?q=braided+cornrows), [tresses plaquées](https://www.google.fr/search?q=tresses+plaqu%C3%A9es) et [tresses collées](https://www.google.fr/search?q=tresses+coll%C3%A9es).

Comment: @Amphiteóth - C'était un site au hasard trouvé par google en demandant "coiffure afro". Je suis donc tombé sur un site pas loin de chez moi, je ne me souviens plus lequel. Quant à la pertinence mesurée par google, il faut noter qu'elle est biaisée à la fois par la localisation du demandeur et par le fait que google agrège tous les résultats francophones sans ventiler par dialecte (France, Québec, Belgique...)

Comment: En effet Google. Plusieurs termes sont concurrents et de plus des concepts reliés à l'optimisation et à l'indexation peuvent interférer. Si qqn conçoit un site, la personne peut facilement décider d'utiliser plusieurs termes pour faciliter la recherche etc. Je n'ai rien trouvé sur un site comme _Franceterme_.

Answer (score 1):

En France, on appelle cela des tresses africaines. Google images en donne plusieurs exemples.

Comment: Merci! Disposez-vous d'une référence qui me permettrait de vérifier l'affirmation? Aussi, le terme _tresse africaine_ est-il générique i.e. permet-il de distinguer des tresses africaines qui ne seraient pas en _cornrows_ ([ceci](http://www.navy.mil/ah_online/um/FHCR.html) vs. [cela](http://www.navy.mil/ah_online/um/FHMicroBraid.html), par exemple)?

Comment: J'ai recherché coiffure [ici](http://www.rncp.cncp.gouv.fr/grand-public/recherche), pour obtenir ce genre de [fiche](http://www.rncp.cncp.gouv.fr/grand-public/visualisationFiche?format=fr&fiche=5142); dans le detail d'une fiche de metier associée i.e. [_CAP Coiffure ROME D1202_](http://candidat.pole-emploi.fr/marche-du-travail/fichemetierrome?codeRome=D1202), on voit sous un onglet "Coiffure afro-antillaise" ainsi que "Tressage" comme types de prestation. J'ai aussi trouvé une bibliographie pour ce genre de [formation](http://www.crdp-montpellier.fr/services/docadm/BP_coiffure.pdf).